# TypeError: fs.readdirSync is not a function React js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I want to import all pictures from a folder to a component with dynamic import like this:

index.js

```
const testFolder = './2020/';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const files = fs.readdirSync(testFolder);
const allowedExts = ['.png', '.jpg', 'svg'] // add any extensions you need
const modules = {};

if (files.length) {
  let filterThruFiles = files.filter(file => allowedExts.indexOf(path.extname(file)) > -1)
  filterThruFiles.forEach(file => modules[file] = `./${file}`);
}

module.exports = modules;
let modulesStringify = JSON.stringify(modules);
fs.writeFileSync('pics-url-list.json', modulesStringify);
```

I get an object with the paths and write it to a file, which works fine:

```
//pics-url-list.json
{
  "1-1.jpg":"./1-1.jpg",
  "1-2.jpg":"./1-2.jpg",
  "1-3.jpg":"./1-3.jpg"
//and so on
  }
```

but when I run npm start, I get this error. The main question is how to access this .json file in an React component? Now no console.log works in the App.js, it only show this error about fs.readdirSync

```
//App.js component
import picList from '../images/pics-url-list.json';
console.log(picList);
```

Comment: `fs` etc are node.js things and can only be done server-side.  You can't work with the user's filesystem (through the browser) using those methods.

Comment: @Joe so there's no way to do this? This is basically making a json file and accessing it in the component, there should be some other way maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to use fs like modules for client-side app.
There is a way to dynamically import all images by using `require.context`
For example,

```
function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}

const images = importAll(require.context('./', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
```

Comment: require.context is not a function